# Quelle est l'origine du mot « binoches » pour désigner les toilettes?

Tags: étymologie, régionalismes, belgique

J'ai déjà souvent entendu utiliser le mot « binoches » en lieu et place de « toilettes » (par exemple dans « Tu paies l'addition pendant que je vais aux binoches ? », mais je ne le trouve [pas](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/binoche) dans le TLF. Une [recherche sur Google](https://encrypted.google.com/search?q=%C3%A9tymologie+binoches+toilettes) m'indique qu'il [s'agit d'un belgicisme](http://www.jchr.be/langage/belgicismes.htm) mais sans en préciser l'origine.

Est-ce que quelqu'un d'autre a déjà entendu cet usage, en particulier hors de Belgique ? Quel serait son origine ?

Comment: Peut-être qu'une réponse viendra du côté de *La Libre Belgique* et de sa rubrique temporaire *[À chaque jour son belgisme](http://www.lalibre.be/culture/livres/article/702194/a-chaque-jour-son-belgicisme.html)*, à surveiller de toutes façons !

Answer (score 12):

"Binoches" est une aphérèse de "cabinoches", forme plaisante de "cabinets", où la terminaison "-et" a été remplacée par la terminaison (elle aussi plaisante) "-oche".  On trouve cette dernière dans des mots  comme "cinoche" (pour "cinéma"), "valoche" (pour "valise") ou "téloche" (pour "télévision").  Cela dit, il semble bien que "binoche(s)" ne soit utilisé et compris qu'en Belgique francophone.

Answer (score 9):

Je ne connaissais pas le mot et ne l'ai jamais entendu en France.

Ma propre recherche sur google m'a montré que, comme dit Joubarc, le mot est d'usage très courant en Belgique :

- [dites les mômans : à quel âge avez-vous acheté le premier pot? Mila semble de plus en plus intéressée par les binoches et veut s'y installer](http://www.lavoixlactee.be/forum/ftopic7258.html)
- [Philippe Geluck est né en 1954 à Bruxelles. Avec son frère aîné graphiste, il dessine une espèce de journal au mur de ses binoches (mot belge pour désigner les toilettes](http://www.ciao.fr/Le_chat_T14_La_marque_du_chat_Philippe_Geluck__Avis_1178001)).
- Dans [un poème](http://denismarion.be/news/461) visiblement belge.
- Et même [une illustration](http://nicoavelo.top-depart.com/vietnam/depart/photo/diapo/a-mon-avis-ce-sont-les-binoches--650-111015.html) du mot !

Mais on trouve aussi le mot *binoche(s)* avec d'autres sens que « toilettes » :

- Dans [un texte de chanson](http://www.leparolier.org/textes/voilapourquoijesuischanteur.htm) (qui pourrait être québécois ?), mais il ne s'agit visiblement pas du lieu d'aisance ici, le contexte ferait plutôt penser à « tronches ».
- De très nombreuses occurrences qui font penser à [quelque chose qui se boit](http://foamtoucher.pagesperso-orange.fr/mdg01.html), j'ai même trouvé un [pack de binoches](http://www.forum4x4.com/threads/33168-echapement-inox.../page4), mais ce n'[est visiblement pas de la bière](http://lacachouette.over-blog.com/article-quoi-de-neuf-71212396.html).
- Une *binoche* c'est aussi un [genre de corbeille en vannerie](http://melesse-de-mon-enfance.pagesperso-orange.fr/html/veillees.htm)

Ce mot *binoche(s)* a semble-t-il divers sens et c'est plus qu'étonnant qu'on ne le trouve dans aucun dictionnaire facilement accessible.

Pour en revenir au sens de « toilettes », comme il s'agit d'un belgicisme ne pourrait-on orienter la recherche vers une origine néerlandaise ? (ma recherche côté allemand que n'a rien donné)

Answer (score 1):

Précisément ce mot était utilisé par les bonnes sœurs du pensionnat pour filles "le Berlemont" à  Bruxelles pour ne pas nommer les toilettes: cela aurait fait vulgaire! Plusieurs générations de jeunes filles ont utilisé ce mot. Depuis la disparition de ce pensionnat je ne sais pas ce qu'il est advenu de ce mot et s'il est toujours en vigueur dans une certaine société belge

Answer (score 1):

Bonjour. Je suis belge francophone en Wallonie. J'ai 52 ans et c'est la première fois que j'entends ce mot.
À mon sens, ce terme est utilisé exclusivement en région bruxelloise...

Comment: 10 ans de moins de mon côté, wallon aussi, mais même constat... jamais entendu ça avant, mème si les autres réponses semblent attester de son existence.

Answer (score 1):

Connu dans ma famille depuis la nuit des temps. Origines anversoise et yproise

Comment: Donc d'origine belge, une source est bien importante.  Voici le centre [help] et bienvenue sur French Language SE.

Answer (score 0):

L'expression plurielle "binoches" en France métropolitaine réfère aux anciennes cabanes de toilette des jardins de campagne.

Comment: Il est utile de préciser ses sources.